# calling selectRow on ng-grid in a jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, ng-grid

I have an jasmine test of an angular controller using ng-grid. I want to call `selectRow(1, true);` on the angular grid, but when I do I get the error `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'selectRow'`

I have a angular controller which sets up an ng-grid like this:

```js
    $scope.myGridOptions = {
            data : 'myData',
            multiSelect: false,
            selectedItems: $scope.mySelectedRow,
            afterSelectionChange: function(data) {;
                if($scope.mySelectedRow === undefined){
                    //do somthing
                }else{
                    //do somthing else
                }
            }
        };
```

I then have an jasmine unit test where I instantiate my controller using the inject function, setting the `scope` object to equal the controllers `$scope`. I then have a bunch of tests that don't involve the grid, and they all run and pass fine.

However I want to test the select handler logic so I am testing it like this:

```js
    it('selecting a row in the table does stuff.', function() {
      //controller created in before each
              rootScope.$digest();//needed to get the controller to initialize
      scope.myGridOptions.$selectRow(1, true);
      expect(scope.resultOfDoingSomthing).toBe("done");
  });
```

Let me know in the comments if more code examples are needed. For background I am using `maven jasime:bdd` to run the tests, so my jasmine configuration is setup by that. I don't think there are any problems with it as I have quite a few other angular-jasmine unit tests that are all working as expected. The ng-grid javascript is included. I have also tried adding `module("ngGrid")` to the `beforeEach` with no change. I also tried adding `beforeEach(module("myMod",['ng-grid']));` But this blew up with an `$injector` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for others following. What I have done is to test the afterSelectionChange directly rather than trying to test it by calling selectRow. To make this effective I had to refactor:

```
    afterSelectionChange: function(data) {;
            if($scope.mySelectedRow === undefined){
                //do somthing
            }else{
                //do somthing else
            }
        }
```

to

```
    afterSelectionChange: function(rowItem, event) {;
            if(rowItem.entity === undefined){
                //do somthing
            }else{
                //do somthing with row rowItem
            }
        }
```

which as you can see makes use of the data passed to it.